# Adding data to highlighted text in JQuery and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, highlight, highlighting

I found this excellent code online for highlighting words in text by wrapping then with `<SPAN>` tags and a user defined class. I use this a few times over for highlighting multiple searches at once without any problems.

What I want to do is add an extra feature to this code to add more data to each of the  tags added using JQuery's .data() method. But the function is so tidy and efficient I cant find where I need to inject it!

I want a function like `highlightJQueryText(elem, str, className, dataName, data)`

```
highlightJQueryText: function (elem, str, className) {
            var regex = new RegExp(str, "gi");
            return elem.each(function () {
            $(this).contents().filter(function() {
                    return this.nodeType == 3 && regex.test(this.nodeValue);
                }).replaceWith(function() {
                        return (this.nodeValue || "").replace(regex, function(match) {
                        return "<span class=\"" + className + "\">" + match + "</span>";
                    });
                });
            });
        }
```

PS. it should add a `span.data("dataName", data)` only to those tags created at the same time. (Not everything in the container with the class "className".) Because I run the function on the same container multiple times for different phrases using the same "ClassName", but still want a different set of data stored on each phrase.

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net that others can modify to help you out

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick :

```
highlightJQueryText: function (elem, str, className, dataName, data) {
    var regex = new RegExp(str, "gi");
    return elem.each(function () {
        $(this).contents().filter(function() {
            return this.nodeType == 3 && regex.test(this.nodeValue);
        }).replaceWith(function() {
            return (this.nodeValue || "").replace(regex, function(match) {
                return "<span data-"+dataName+"=\""+data+"\" \
                              class=\""+className+"\">"+match+"</span>";
            });
        });
    });
}
```

or if you really want to use the JQuery `data` method :

```
highlightJQueryText: function (elem, str, className, dataName, data) {
    var regex = new RegExp(str, "gi");
    return elem.each(function () {
    $(this).contents().filter(function() {
            return this.nodeType == 3 && regex.test(this.nodeValue);
        }).replaceWith(function() {
            return (this.nodeValue || "").replace(regex, function(match) {
                return $("<span class=\""+className+"\">"+match+"</span>")
                    .data(dataName, data);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but the first method had issues with deep json objects and the second method just replaces the text with "[Object object]"